# Count characters with contenteditable and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, count, contenteditable

I have a contentediable div tag and need to count characters. However I got the wrong count when it find `&nbsp;` (after deleted some characters). For me in this case it's just 1 character, not 5.

How can I get around it? I use HTML and jQuery.

**I do something like this:**

```
<div class="preview" contenteditable="true">Content with spaces</div>
<script>
$('.preview').on('keyup',function(){
    var len = $(this).html().length;
    console.log(len);
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML Clean plug-in for jQuery

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/